# Invalid pointer operation error - TImage object

Tags: c++builder, c++builder-10.2-tokyo

I'm coding with C++Builder 10.2.

Every time I load a picture to my `TImage` object, I get an "Invalid pointer operation" error:

[image: picture]

This happens whenever I load an image, or even if I haven't loaded any, it happens when I move the blank `TImage` object.

I know it should be shared with Embarcadero devs/supports, but I can also share the error codes.

Comment: Why don't you share your code? Have you tried debugging?

Comment: @NicoHaase It looks like a compiler originated error(to me). It doesn't happen when I run or debug and run the program. It happens any time I load a picture as i said. If it is the error details you are asking, I can share it hoping not to get smited by the community(it's kinda long).

Comment: The image is of an IDE crash at design-time, in which case there would be no user code involved.  This definitely needs to be reported as a bug to Embarcadero.

Comment: @RemyLebeau exactly, it has nothing to do with the code. Almost 500 lines of code is working perfectly, after I decided to move the things I draw on a form's canvas to an image canvas, I faced this issue. I'm going to report as a bug, thanks.

Comment: Did you actually construct the image?

Comment: @RudyVelthuis no it was a .png from an outside source. I even converted it to bitmap, thinking it was about the image format. But then I realized, TImage object itself gives the same error even if it’s blank.

Comment: If you want to report it as a bug, I guess you need a [MCVE] too. Why don't you post one here (in your question)?

Comment: @RudyVelthuis sir, any specific part of my project will not make any sense to observers. It’s mostly math equations, iterations and some standard TObject events(i.e onchange). There’s only one thing that might be related to the issue: I have a display form, on which(its canvas) I draw parallel line(2D) and meridian curve of any point, but the equations which give the parameters of the point are all around the source file, so I would need to share the entire .cpp file and static libs. I understand how important the sample code, but after all I’m adding a TImage object, I’m not even running it.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem with Timage on c++ builder 2010.
It seems that is IDE bug and we have to create and free memory used by Timage manually.

This problem will not occur in the new version of Delphi(Rad studio 11 alexandria)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).